# join 2 query from different database

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

Hi is this the right way to join 2 query from different database? or there is no way to join 2 database in one 1 function

**Model.php**

```
public function getUserGroup($userId = null) 
    {
        if($userId) {
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM user_group WHERE user_id = ?";
            $query = $this->db->query($sql, array($userId));
            $result = $query->row_array();

            $group_id = $result['group_id'];
            $g_sql = "SELECT * FROM groups WHERE id = ?";
            $g_query = $this->db->query($g_sql, array($group_id));

            $store_id = $result['store_id'];
            $s_sql = "SELECT * FROM stores WHERE id = ?";
            $s_query = $this->db->query($s_query, array($store_id));
            $s_result = $s_query->row_array();

            $t_result= $g_query ->row_array(), $s_result->row_array();
            return $t_result;
        }
    }
```

Comment: are you really meaning different databases, or maybe just multiple tables?

For me it looks like the `$this->db` object belongs to one database (because it's the same object and you don't reconfigure it)

Comment: i  mean table bro, my bad

Answer (score 0):

you can join table in mysql query is below demo [link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=9f985436e6ceb4d4df8961a9df9a24b4)

```
CREATE TABLE user_group (user_id INT,group_id INT,store_id INT);

INSERT INTO user_group VALUES (1,1,1);
INSERT INTO user_group VALUES (1,1,2);
INSERT INTO user_group VALUES (2,1,1);
INSERT INTO user_group VALUES (2,1,2);
-- fetch 
SELECT * FROM user_group;

CREATE TABLE `groups` (group_id INT,group_name varchar(255));

INSERT INTO `groups` VALUES (1,'group-1');
INSERT INTO `groups` VALUES (2,'group-2');

SELECT * FROM `groups`;


CREATE TABLE stores (store_id INT,store_name varchar(100));

INSERT INTO stores VALUES (1,'store-1');
INSERT INTO stores VALUES (2,'store-2');

SELECT * FROM stores;



SELECT * FROM user_group ug 
JOIN `groups` g on g.group_id = ug.group_id
JOIN stores s on s.store_id = ug.store_id
WHERE ug.user_id = 1;
```

and you can use codeigniter(CI)query like below and for your reference [link](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html?highlight=join)

```
 $this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('user_group');
$this->db->join('groups', 'groups.group_id = user_group.group_id');
$this->db->join('stores', 'stores.store_id = user_group.store_id');
$this->db->where('user_group.user_id', 1); // <--- "1" = that is your's $userId 
$query = $this->db->get();
```